# One computer connects to multiple VLANs with inter-VLAN routing

Tags: vlan

Let says I have two VLANs, `10.0.1.x` and `192.168.1.x`. These 2 VLANs have inter VLAN routing enabled.

Computer **A**: connected to `192.168.1.x` with IP `192.168.1.2`

Computer **B**: connected to both. `10.0.1.3` and `192.168.1.3`

When I ping `192.168.1.3` from **A**, it is okay. But if I ping `10.0.1.3`, it fails.

However, if I turn off the `192.168.1.3` interface on computer **B**, then I can reach `10.0.1.3` from **A**.

Why is that so? What can I do to solve the situation? Any routing table issue involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's perfectly normal.

When you ping `10.0.1.3` you emit a ICMP *echo request* packet with source address `192.168.1.2` and destination address of `10.0.1.3`, and expect a response with source address `10.0.1.3` / destination address `192.168.1.2`

When the computer **B** responds, it sends a response to `192.168.1.2`. 
Since it has an interface in the same network, with it's IP `192.168.1.3`, it sends the response trough this interface, so the ICMP *echo reply* message is sent with source address `192.168.1.3` / destination address `192.168.1.2`.

Computer **A** does receive the response but it's not the expected source address, so it does not associate it with the initial echo request.

Now if you turn off the interface `192.168.1.3`, the response is sent trough the other interface with the correct IP address.

Concerning how to solve the situation, it all depends on why you do have computer **B** multi-homed (I.E. connected to several networks). It's better in most case to avoid this kind of setup.

One way to do it would be to NAT the `10.0.1.X` address to `192.168.1.x` address for example.

Answer (score 0):

You may be hit by Reverse Path Filtering. Basically Computer **B** is dropping the incoming ICMP-packets since it wasn't expecting IP packets from `192.168.1.2` on the `10.0.1.3` interface.

It is expecting traffic from the `192.168.1.0/24` subnet from the `192.168.1.3` interface.